# How many factory method can be declared and defined in a module AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in Angular JS.
I tried to declare more than one factory methods for my module. It was not allowing me to run the code. Can any one help me with an JSFIDDLE example showing if more than one factory methods be created and also how it can be minified while compressing.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('apiTokenOne', ['clientId', function apiTokenFactoryOne(clientId) {
      ----
      return "";
}];

app.factory('apiTokenTwo', ['clientId', function apiTokenFactoryTwo(clientId) {
      ----
      return "";
}];
```

Please correct me, If I am wrong. All your advises are appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35151864/revisions)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your factory should be something like this:

```
app.factory('apiTokens', function() {
     return {
         apiTokenOne: function(clientId){
             //do stuff
             //return token 
         },
         apiTokenTwo: function(clientId){
             //do stuff
             //return token;
         }
     }
});
```

then in controller:

```
$scope.token = apiTokens.apiTokenOne(cliendId);
```